# Pass value from my view to my model

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

i want to pass a value from my view to my model. i want to pass the $plate value to my model to get all the data that will match the $plate. here is my code:

View

```
<a href="<?=base_url()?>services/view_services?plate=<?php echo  $plate; ?>">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">View Services</button>
```

Controller

```
public function view_services()
{
    $data['results'] = $this->Services_model->fetch_car_services($config['per_page'], $page);
    $this->load->view('car_services', $data);
}
```

Model

```
public function fetch_car_services($plate)
{
    $this->db->where('car_plate_number =', $plate);
    $this->db->order_by('created_datetime', 'DESC');
    $query = $this->db->get('service_jobs');
    $result = $query->result();
    $this->db->save_queries = false;

    return $result;
}
```

it doesn't seem to work. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is your controller? e.g. the layer between your view and model

Comment: please see edited post

Comment: i think you edited it incorrectly, you seem to know that you want to pass $plate to fetch car services yet in your first parameter in your controller of fetch car  services you have $config['per_page']??

Answer (score 1):

You have to get the variable somehow, using your method:

```
//services/view_services?plate=someplate
public function view_services() {
    $plate = $this->input->get('plate');
    if (is_null($plate)) {
        // error!
    }
    $data['results'] = $this->Services_model->fetch_car_services($plate);
    $this->load->view('car_services', $data);
}
```

a better way of doing things:

```
//services/view_services/someplate
public function view_services($plate = null) {
    if (is_null($plate)) {
        // error!
    }
    $data['results'] = $this->Services_model->fetch_car_services($plate);
    $this->load->view('car_services', $data);
}
```

Please check for errors! I already did half the work for you here, you just have to figure out how you want to handle them. This also includes checking if `num_rows > 0` in your model or `count($data['results']) > 0` in your controller and sending an error if that is the case. Your foreach in your view will fail if you don't.

Answer (score 0):

View :

```
 <a href="<?php echo site_url('services/view_services/').$plate; ?>"></a>
```

Controller:

```
 public function view_services($plate)
     {
         $data['results'] = $this->Services_model->fetch_car_services($config['per_page'], $page);

         $this->load->view('car_services', $data);
     }
```